# Generate, store/restore public/private keys in node

Tags: node.js, serialization, cryptography

I'm working on a node.js application which uses "elliptic" npm.

```
var EC = require('elliptic').ec;
 
// Create and initialize EC context
// (better do it once and reuse it)
var ec = new EC('secp256k1');
 
// Generate keys
var key = ec.genKeyPair();
// Sign the message's hash (input must be an array, or a hex-string)
var msgHash = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
var signature = key.sign(msgHash);
```

I want to make the `key` object survive the app restart. Any easy way to store it on disk somehow and load it next time?

Comment: A bit of browsing in the source code suggests `var bkey = key.getPrivate().toArray('be', bytes);`. Horrid documentation.

Comment: So, I did figure out how to get private/public keys from the keyPair, which I can store in a file on disk. The question is, how can I create a new instance of KeyPair from private and public  strings, so that I can use the KeyPair for signing?

Comment: Generally you do **not** want to save private keys into strings, especially not without first encrypting them. However, any binary value can be converted to string using base 64.

Comment: It just does not make sense. There has to a way in JS to store and retrieve the keypair, so that the same keys can be used as identity which survives software sessions restarts. I just can't believe nothing like this exists in JS -- in my understanding this is a fundamental requirement.

Comment: In other words, when I produce a new key pair with call to ec.genKeyPair(), it's not that useful unless there is a way to persist it somehow and reconstruct the same exact object when my software restarts.